# There's no longer any point in storing users' real names on public Q&A sites now that its prior uses no longer exist; can it please be removed?

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, real-name, pii

**TL;DR**: I don't think there's any point in having a field for a user's real name in their public Q&A profile now that the only two real uses for it, for use by Stack Overflow Jobs and Stack Overflow for Teams, have been removed. Per the principle of [only retaining PII that serves a real purpose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47718/display-a-happy-birthday-message-when-a-user-logs-in-on-their-birthday/340427#comment1137794_340427), this field should be removed.

---

This came to my attention when I saw [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377816/reference-to-developer-story-when-editing-user-profiles-on-all-sites-except-stac), regarding the message shown to users warning them that updating their real name on all sites (including Stack Overflow) will change their name on Jobs-related functionality on the site, and that it isn't relevant anymore now that Jobs has been permanently discontinued. This got me thinking: this field isn't really used at all now as far as I can tell.

The only other use of the field on Stack Overflow, previously, was in Stack Overflow for Teams: originally, one's username on Teams sites would be pulled from and synced with the user's set real name on Stack Overflow. However, [since 2019](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386450/2157772), users' profile info on Teams (including usernames) is now dissociated from and no longer synced with their public Q&A profile info. Since the 2022 dissociation of Teams from public Q&A, the final real case where it was used was when a user joined a new Team: the default, pre-filled name would be pulled from the real name on public Q&A profile. This is no longer the case following the 2022 changes. Even prior to that, the user had the option to change it separately, and a fallback already existed for when a user doesn't have their real name previously set: they'd be prompted to enter it when joining.

Finally, there's not much use for storing this information on profiles for other network sites. The only case where it is (or was) used outside of Stack Overflow is in the homepage sidebar block on beta sites to invite others by email to use the site: there's an option to either make the email appear to be from one's display name or from their set real name (prior to 2015, it [always used one's real name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247577/my-real-name-was-used-in-a-beta-invite-email)). But an alternative feature can easily be implemented so functionality isn't lost: just make the second option a text field that a user can enter any name they wish. Outside of that, there's *absolutely no use whatsoever* for one's real name on non-beta sites other than Stack Overflow.

A similar thing was previously done with the birth date field in the profile: previously, this had a purpose, to show the user's age to other users, but that feature was removed in a 2015 redesign. When GDPR was adopted three years later, the field was removed and all information entered into it was deleted, per the new working principle that [the only PII that should be stored is that which is actually used](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47718/display-a-happy-birthday-message-when-a-user-logs-in-on-their-birthday/340427#comment1137794_340427): as birth dates weren't used anywhere anymore, the field was removed. The same thing is true today for the real name field on public Q&A.

To summarize, there is no longer any use case where saving one's real name is necessary for site functionality to work on public Q&A, as in the sole previous cases where it was used - for Jobs and the previous configuration of Teams - it's no longer used. It's never been used anywhere on other non-beta network sites, and a fallback can easily be implemented for its sole use on beta sites.

Given the above, can the field on public Q&A be removed? (I should probably add that the same field also exists on Area 51, where it also isn't used anywhere - in fact, in the sole case where one's real name is used there, when committing to proposals, it actually *prompts* to enter one's real name rather than getting it from their profile. One might argue that Area 51 uses a dated engine, but the birth date field *was* removed from there as well in 2018.)

Comment: *"If the feature is still to exist for users joining subsequent Teams instances, it can be pulled from a user's profile on an existing Team they're a part of."* Definitely cannot do that. We cannot access information inside a team for use in a context outside of that team. But past that, I agree. Nothing really comes to mind where this field is still useful - it's not a huge inconvenience to just have users type in their name when creating a team. That said, investigating something like this probably won't happen until all the Jobs code has actually been ripped out and not just turned off.

Comment: There are advantages and uses for this field which may not be immediately obvious, and which it is out of scope to discuss here. It should definitely be retained. Your conclusion that it was only used by Teams and/or Jobs is erroneous. This field *long* pre-dated the introduction of both Teams and Jobs. You have failed to make any actual arguments, aside from your own lack of understanding where/how it is used, in favor of its removal. Effort should not be put into removing things without a clear and compelling reason. "I don't see the need" is not such a reason.

Comment: @CodyGray Is that reason related to moderation purposes? Also, by the way, the argument isn't "I don't see the need"; it's "collected PII that's not used for any real purpose and can be prompted for when needed".

Comment: @CodyGray if it's PII there needs to be a compelling reason to keep it, not to remove it which should be the default (should go without saying).

Comment: @bad_coder & Sonic: Cody very explicitly stated that there are existing uses for this field which are "out of scope to discuss here" that long predate the existence of Teams. That *you* don't see the need/use is irrelevant to *this* discussion and retorting that PII shouldn't be collected/kept without need is *counterproductive*, given Cody said there is a need/use. OTOH, you could argue that the existing need/use doesn't justify having it, but that's a *different* argument than merely repeating the obvious and previously stated argument that PII shouldn't be collected/kept without use/need.

Comment: I agree Cody saying "Effort should not be put into removing things without a clear and compelling reason." was not very nuanced, and that a need/use for collecting and retaining PII is required. However, Cody very clearly first stated there is such need/use for this data. Cody was, probably, largely speaking a bit expansively from frustration as a result of all the recent changes to the site which have, along with making the site much less usable and introducing bugs, removed considerable information (some good, some bad, but almost universally not well thought out, at least to begin with).

Comment: I also understand substantial frustration on your part and in general from seeing SE's general collection and retention of PII. The entire industry has a poor track record regarding collecting and retaining PII. While SE does appear notably better than average (which isn't a high bar), they have a poor track record on multiple issues. They've had to be literally hounded over months/years about some/multiple issues where they have, IMO, *very* obviously been in the wrong (from multiple points of view). That is, certainly, frustrating.

Comment: @Makyen Okay...what exact need is there for this data? It would be nice to know. I'm personally on the side of "don't collect PII unless it's absolutely necessary", so I'd like to know what "such a need/use for this data" Cody was talking about.

Comment: This information is actually still used in one rather hidden site function. The winner of every moderator election is sent an email that starts with "Hi [full name]". Just as a reminder that they've got your PII as much as you have theirs, I guess. Needless to say, I don't think that is necessary.

Comment: Well, it might be useful in some future feature SE will add, so I really see no harm in asking the user for their real name. It's not mandatory, if one doesn't want to share it, they can simply leave the field blank. So removing it serves no purpose.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars That would be absolutely true if it weren't for GDPR and other privacy laws hamstringing what information they can store about users but not use. That's why the birth date feature was removed in 2018, as animuson's comment I link to first in my post says.